# Onboard graphics stop working after installing graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

After installing an AMD Radeon HD 7470 in my old Optiplex 380 computer, the onboard graphics have stopped working. I'm trying to connect two monitors, one of them being connected to graphics card and other to the on board VGA port. The one connected to on board VGA port doesn't work at all.

Comment: Desktops tend to be either/or, unlike laptops. The upside is you can get GPUs that will support 3, 4 or even 6 displays.